# Why do identical model instances generated using PyTorch produce different outputs, and what are the solutions?

Tags: pytorch

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.backends import cudnn

seed = 0
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
cudnn.deterministic = True
cudnn.benchmark = False

class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
          super(SimpleNet, self).__init__()
          self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
      def forward(self, x):
          out = self.fc1(x)
    
          return out

input_size = 10
hidden_size = 20
output_size = 5

# device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

device = 'cpu'
input_data = torch.randn(32, input_size)
input_data = input_data.to(device)

model = SimpleNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)

output1 = model(input_data)

print(output1)
model = SimpleNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)

# del output1

output2 = model(input_data)
print(output2)
model = SimpleNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)

output3 = model(input_data)
print(output3)
```

output:

tensor([[-1.5116,  1.0399,  0.5818,  0.4947,  0.2639, -0.1309,  0.3110,  0.4311,
-0.6150,  0.4050, -0.1481, -0.3213,  0.6688,  0.5720, -0.1721,  0.1600,
0.0351,  1.0659,  0.2054,  0.1556],
[-0.1409, -0.4082, -0.7771,  0.3325, -0.7576, -0.3052, -0.3914, -0.0429,
-1.0385,  0.3136, -0.0378, -0.7738,  0.3380,  0.7558,  0.2281, -0.9408,
-1.0762,  0.3762, -0.6075, -0.9881],
[ 1.0371, -0.3052, -0.7192, -0.4954, -0.0619, -0.6773, -0.3437, -0.1149,
-0.7098, -0.0663,  0.2402, -0.1380, -0.0546, -0.1480, -0.3620, -1.0165,
-0.4548,  0.6009, -0.1641, -0.7223],
[-0.6194,  0.2212,  0.2156,  0.5785, -0.1053, -0.2406, -0.0536,  0.2633,
-0.0827,  0.2190,  0.1406, -0.3082,  0.4105, -0.0564, -0.4030, -0.6807,
-0.2153,  1.0450,  0.2360, -0.2577],
[ 1.5008,  0.2273,  0.2086, -1.4349, -0.8325, -0.0553, -1.9506,  1.0662,
-0.9117, -0.7985,  0.2942, -0.4245, -0.6362, -0.6082,  0.3804, -0.4315,
-1.2882, -0.4164,  0.9965, -0.7636]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
tensor([[ 0.3480,  0.3380, -0.4902, -0.1727, -1.4587, -1.7824, -0.5210, -1.4188,
0.8898, -1.6112, -0.6507, -0.4776, -0.6237,  0.2907, -0.1367, -0.8204,
-0.1833,  0.0711,  1.3449, -0.9399],
[-0.3995, -0.1740,  0.0406,  0.5558, -1.1816, -0.0281,  0.1738, -0.0590,
0.1638,  0.4439,  0.6594, -0.0111, -0.1184,  0.2536, -1.1477, -0.6620,
-0.5626,  0.3007, -0.2232, -0.0159],
[-0.6477,  0.0387,  0.0104,  0.6004, -0.5215,  0.2377,  0.3120,  0.5024,
-0.1435,  1.0267, -0.0850,  0.5509, -0.1720,  0.7758, -0.4568,  0.0568,
-0.3941,  0.0733,  0.0714,  0.1224],
[-0.1056,  0.4826, -0.4121, -0.2473, -0.6680, -0.6018,  0.1496, -0.6604,
0.7170, -0.0660, -0.2835,  0.4953,  0.0948,  0.3696, -0.4176, -0.3242,
-0.1028, -0.0509,  0.9921, -0.8176],
[ 0.3800, -0.1418,  0.6162, -0.6415,  1.1636,  2.1334, -0.2372, -0.4634,
0.0067,  0.7677,  0.2029, -0.5407,  1.7590,  1.2410,  0.9184,  0.6625,
-0.6612,  0.2142, -0.7860,  0.0127]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
tensor([[-0.0243,  1.0001,  0.7106,  0.4752, -0.0075, -1.1864,  0.2284, -0.1393,
-0.9675, -1.0423, -0.2470,  0.7237,  0.3109,  0.0975,  0.7873, -0.6733,
-1.1279, -0.2281, -0.2457, -0.0767],
[ 0.5381,  0.3391,  0.6314,  0.5580, -0.0700, -0.4536,  0.8431,  0.0564,
0.7927, -0.3688,  0.1646,  0.2029,  0.2588,  0.0048,  0.1181,  0.2797,
0.1471,  0.4008, -0.9551,  0.0732],
[ 0.2266, -0.4448, -0.4133,  0.9179,  0.3264, -0.0059,  0.4354,  0.4920,
1.1738, -0.7267,  0.9867, -0.7227,  0.6543,  1.0040, -0.7897,  0.0184,
0.4296,  0.4448,  0.1173,  0.1869],
[ 0.0907,  0.1008,  0.6054,  0.2081, -0.4937, -0.9011, -0.1375, -0.2694,
-0.0065, -1.1464,  0.2610,  0.0738,  0.9818,  0.0983,  0.1097, -0.4880,
-0.6180, -0.0958, -0.0334,  0.2447],
[-0.0593,  0.8875, -1.4164,  0.4210,  2.2157,  0.9704,  0.0399,  0.9641,
1.0622,  1.3101,  0.5949,  0.8925, -0.6213,  1.2130,  0.2840,  0.5771,
0.7983, -0.5174,  0.6473,  0.2891]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)

How to make their outputs the same?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because every instantiation of SimpleNet initializes weights using the random number generator. When you instantiate for the second time, the state of the random number generator is different from the first time.

To solve this, you can repeat

```
seed = 0
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
```

before the second instantiation and again before the third.